# Python script to import registry key

Tags: python, registrykey

I have a registry key that contains information for a program that I am running. I have registry key exported to a directory and I can easily import using the regedit Import function. I am having trouble writing a script that does the same using python..

I can read existing keys using the following:

```
    import _winreg as wreg
    test = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer', 0, wreg.KEY_READ)
    print test
```

But where I'm having trouble is Importing the key from the directory on my desktop.

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.call(['reg','import',filename])`

Answer (score 2):

Xmcp's comment was actually the answer:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['reg', 'import', filename])
```